# Pandas difference between groupby-size and unique

Tags: python, pandas, unique

The goal here is to see how many unique values i have in my database. This is the code i have written:

```
apps = pd.read_csv('ConcatOwned1_900.csv', sep='\t', usecols=['appid'])

apps[('appid')] = apps[('appid')].astype(int)
apps_list=apps['appid'].unique()

b = apps.groupby('appid').size()
blist = b.unique()

print len(apps_list), len(blist), len(set(b))
>>>7672 2164 2164
```

Why is there difference in those two methods?

Due to request i am posting some of my data:

```
Unnamed: 0  StudID          No  appid work work2
0   0   76561193665298433   0   10  nan 0
1   1   76561193665298433   1   20  nan 0
2   2   76561193665298433   2   30  nan 0
3   3   76561193665298433   3   40  nan 0
4   4   76561193665298433   4   50  nan 0
5   5   76561193665298433   5   60  nan 0
6   6   76561193665298433   6   70  nan 0
7   7   76561193665298433   7   80  nan 0
8   8   76561193665298433   8   100 nan 0
9   9   76561193665298433   9   130 nan 0
10  10  76561193665298433   10  220 nan 0
11  11  76561193665298433   11  240 nan 0
12  12  76561193665298433   12  280 nan 0
13  13  76561193665298433   13  300 nan 0
14  14  76561193665298433   14  320 nan 0
15  15  76561193665298433   15  340 nan 0
16  16  76561193665298433   16  360 nan 0
17  17  76561193665298433   17  380 nan 0
18  18  76561193665298433   18  400 nan 0
19  19  76561193665298433   19  420 nan 0
20  20  76561193665298433   20  500 nan 0
21  21  76561193665298433   21  550 nan 0
22  22  76561193665298433   22  620 6.0 3064
33  33  76561193665298434   0   10  nan 837
34  34  76561193665298434   1   20  nan 27
35  35  76561193665298434   2   30  nan 9
36  36  76561193665298434   3   40  nan 5
37  37  76561193665298434   4   50  nan 2
38  38  76561193665298434   5   60  nan 0
39  39  76561193665298434   6   70  nan 403
40  40  76561193665298434   7   130 nan 0
41  41  76561193665298434   8   80  nan 6
42  42  76561193665298434   9   100 nan 10
43  43  76561193665298434   10  220 nan 14
```

Comment: size count then umber of row, there can be duplicates ... unique is the number of different unique elements.

Comment: could you show your dataframe to better understanding?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov i posted some, hopes they help

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel well unique gives much more than size as you can see

Comment: Where is your `'appid'` column in that dataframe?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov sorry for that, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC based on attached piece of the dataframe it seems that you should analyze `b.index`, not values of `b`. Just look:

```
b = apps.groupby('appid').size()

In [24]: b  
Out[24]:    
appid       
10     2    
20     2    
30     2    
40     2    
50     2    
60     2    
70     2    
80     2    
100    2    
130    2    
220    2    
240    1    
280    1    
300    1    
320    1    
340    1    
360    1    
380    1    
400    1    
420    1    
500    1    
550    1    
620    1    
dtype: int64

In [25]: set(b)
Out[25]: {1, 2}
```

But if you do it for `b.index` you'll get the same values for all 3 methods:

```
blist = b.index.unique()

In [30]: len(apps_list), len(blist), len(set(b.index))
Out[30]: (23, 23, 23)
```